# Does a view capture only a query, or also the data behind that query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does a view capture only a query, or also the data behind that query?

Comment: thanks.can you give me its answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view is just a stored query.

Comment: we can create index on view(indexedview) whats it meaning that....if there is no data in view than what to mean that we want to create index on it..

Comment: An index on a table indexes the whole table. An index on a view indexes the resolved views data. For example if the view had a where clause or join then the index may contain a subset of the table data or data from multiple tables. The index improves the performance of the view. But the view is still just a stored query.

Answer (score 1):

A view is simply stored T-SQL unless if it is an indexed view in which case [it must have at least a unique clustered index and will therefore be stored in the same way as a table with a clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx).